# does tensorflow tf.slice incur allocation and/or memory copy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management

Does

```
b = tf.slice(a, [...], [...])
```

allocate a new memory buffer and then copy from a's buffer?  or do a and b share the same buffer?

And, what about

```
... = tf.nn.convolution(tf.slice(a, [...], [...]), ...)
```

In this case, the slice is not being named.  Does this incur an allocation and copy?

In general, is there some resource for learning these memory management details?

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag the language python. "tensorflow" is not a language, it is an API.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed.  Although the syntax of my code is python, this question is not specific to python since it is only a binding.  That's why I was hesitant to tag it as python.

Comment: Be aware that the answer may depend on the language as well.

Comment: @cs95: No, this answer will not depend on the language. It is the `SliceOp` in TF, no matter what language you use.

Answer (score 4):

I was curious of this as well and went into the kernel implementation of [`tf.slice`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1023a54b03751d859468905403e2ae7f4faf4e60/tensorflow/core/kernels/slice_op.cc#L158-L191).

The only time memory is not allocated is when the slice is the identity slice (so there are no changes), and when the slice is dimension 0 aligned.

[Identity Lines](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/slice_op.cc#L138-L143)

```
  if (is_identity) {
    VLOG(1) << "Slice identity";
    context->set_output(0, input);
    *done = true;
    return;
  }
```

[Dim0Aligned](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5fb82fc0184b199d302757bfb4f0a57921a8acf0/tensorflow/core/kernels/slice_op.cc#L145-L152)

```
  if (slice_dim0 &&
      IsDim0SliceAligned<T>(input.shape(), (*begin)[0], (*size)[0])) {
    VLOG(1) << "Slice dim 0: " << input.shape().DebugString();
    CHECK_GE(input.dims(), 1);  // Otherwise, is_identity should be true.
    context->set_output(0, input.Slice((*begin)[0], (*begin)[0] + (*size)[0]));
    *done = true;
    return;
  }
```

Otherwise the following will be called

```
  OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, *output_shape, result));
```

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Is the data copied when sliced? Yes or no?

Comment: @LucG, if you are slicing with identity slice or a dimension 0 aligned slice there is no data copy. Otherwise, there is a copy.

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing, it all makes sense now. Sorry.