# Is there any contiguous function in tensorflow2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

In PyTorch, people usually call `tensor.permute(2,0,1,3).contiguous()`. If I call this function in tensorflow 2.0, is it enough to just call `tf.reshape(tensor, perm = [2, 0, 1, 3])`?

or what is a contiguous function in tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: You stated a potential solution (`tf.reshape..`). So, haven't you tried it already? If so, what's the issue (error or reliability)?

Comment: There is no issue, but I don't know whether the memory of tensor become contiguous or not. Therefore, I want to explicitly make tensor contiguous, but I can't find contiguous function in Tensorflow.

Comment: Can you go through this question and conversation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53398721/9215780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official docs of [tf.transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose),

> In `NumPy`, transposes are memory-efficient constant time operations as they simply return a **new view of the same data with adjusted strides**. `TensorFlow` does not support strides, so transpose returns **a new tensor with the items permuted**.

Also, `TensorFlow` doesn't seem to support Fortran (Column-Major) ordering. Hence, I think we automatically get Contiguous (Row-Major) ordering tensor.