# How can I apply a TensorFlow 2D Convolution (tf.nn.conv2d) to a single (non-batch) 2D image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

I would like to use the function `tf.nn.conv2d()` on a **single** image example, but the TensorFlow documentation seems to only mention applying this transformation to a **batch** of images.

The docs mention that the input image must be of shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]` and the kernel must be of shape `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`. However, what is the most straightforward way to achieve 2D convolution with input shape `[in_height, in_width, in_channels]`?

Here is an example of the current approach, where `img` has shape (height, width, channels):

```
img = tf.random_uniform((10,10,3))  # a single image
img = tf.nn.conv2d([img], kernel)[0] # creating a batch of 1, then indexing the single example
```

I am reshaping the input as follows:

`[in_height, in_width, in_channels]->[1, in_height, in_width, in_channels]->[in_height, in_width, in_channels]`

This feels like an unnecessary and costly operation when I am only interested in transforming one example.

Is there a simple/standard way to do this that doesn't involve reshaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way around it. It seems ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779869/does-tensorflow-tf-slice-incur-allocation-and-or-memory-copy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398721/tensorflow-can-reshape-create-a-copy)) that the first operation creates a copy (someone correct me if I'm wrong). You may use [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) instead though, it's IMO more readable because of it's verbosity.

On the other hand, taking `0` element from the tensor should not perform a copy in this case and is almost free.

**Most importantly**, except for a little inconvenience with syntax (e.g. `[0]`) those operations definitely **are not costly**, especially in the context of performing convolution.

BTW. Other ready alternative layers like the ones in `tf.keras`, require batch as first dimension as well.